# use url helper in Controller

Tags: image, url, cakephp

I need to locate an image from the controller, I have tried the following:

```
<img src="<?echo $this->webroot; ?>img/logo_comprobante.jpg"/>
```

but does not work me, is there any way?

Comment: "locate"? this outputs an image tag which should not be happening in the controller layer. HTML should only be outputted by the view layer.

Comment: I build an HTML code from my controller before being loaded into a plugin editing.

Comment: That is the complete wrong way, you break the MVC pattern with this. Messy code ahead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should do it:

```
$www_root = Router::url('/',true);
$img_url = $www_root.'img/logo_comprobante.jpg';
//or
$img_url = Router::url('/img/logo_comprobante.jpg',true);
```

Comment: instead of the decprecated constant use `$wwwRoot = Router::url('/', true);` - or directly `Router::url('/img/logo_comprobante.jpg')` as it doesnt have to be absolute including schema/host.

Comment: Thanks Mark, your suggestion is the better way.. have updated accordingly